# In multiple HTTP Spring Security annotation configuration only one security is applied

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Trying to apply multiple http configuration as described in the documentation [multiple-httpsecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)

Using Spring-4.1.6.RELEASE and Spring-Security-4.0.1.RELEASE (also tried 3.2.7.RELEASE)

As a result I'm getting only the basic auth applied against the /api/** pattern the formLogin is not working. 
In the filterChain object during debug we can see that the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is missing.

[image]

On the other hand when tried to apply the @Order(1) annotation to the FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead to the ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter, got only the formLogin authentication applied. In the filterChain object during debug we can see that the BasicAuthenticationFilter is missing.

[image]

Feel free to use the source code of the project to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/kmarabet/SpringSecurityMultiHttpSample

Comment: It will be helpful if you show some code in your `WebSecurityConfig`.

Comment: https://github.com/kmarabet/SpringSecurityMultiHttpSample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/config/ExtendedSecurityConfig.java